# Replicate two clusters with each other

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication, galera, multi-master-replication

I'm currently having one Galera cluster in Europe, I'd like to run another cluster in the United States and use master - master replication between the two clusters.

I know I could just make one big cluster, but this would be bad for the performance of the cluster because of the latency of the node's between the two continents.

Question:

1. Is it possible to use master - master replication to replicate a cluster to another cluster?
2. Should I choose two node's (one in each cluster) for the master - master replication? or is it possible to link multiple node's like below:

Server1-cluster 1 - server 1-cluster2

Server2-cluster 1 - server 2-cluster2

Server3-cluster 1 - server 3-cluster2

Answer (score 0):

Only do one M-M link between the two clusters.  If there are 3 M-M links, then you will get lots of "duplicate key" errors.

Be sure to avoid `AUTO_INCREMENTs` and `UNIQUE` keys that could cause trouble.